# Why using a variable change the output of echo using zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

As input, I have a file named exp_multiple_512_0 with 11 lines containing numbers. I'm using zsh.

If I do:

```
echo $(cut -f1 exp_multiple_512_0)
```

I have:

```
0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000
```

However, if I change my line by:

```
v=$(cut -f1 exp_multiple_512_0) 
echo $v
```

I have:

```
0
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
1000
```

But when I use bash, I still get: `0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000`

My questions are:

- What should be the correct behavior? Keeping or not the returns?
- Why using an intermediate variable allows me to keep the carriage returns?
- Can I configure zsh to behave more like bash on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer was from chepnet who said in a comment:

> zsh does not perform word-splitting on parameter expansions by
>   default, meaning any embedded newlines are treated literally instead
>   of as word-separating whitespace. setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT makes zsh
>   behave like bash. The issue is with echo $v vs echo "$v", not the
>   $(cut ...).

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes in your echo:

```
echo "$(cut -f1 exp_multiple_512_0)"
```

or simply:

```
cut -f1 exp_multiple_512_0
```

Then you will get newlines as you're getting in your second command.

Without quotes around shell prints space for newlines.

Comment: That's interesting. However, I'd like to avoid those newlines in fact. And I'd like to understand why using an intermediate variable change the result.

Comment: Are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: I'm actually using both. zsh is my interactive shell and I use bash for my scripts. In my case, that's for bash so I don't have any problem, but I'd like to understand why zsh behave likes that and I'd like a solution compatible with both.

Comment: In this particular case zsh and bash behave differently. If you do `echo $v` in BASH you won't see any new lines which is not the case with zsh.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm saying in my question... Why zsh keeps the newlines when I am using an intermediate variable?

Comment: Well quite simply put `zsh is not identical to bash` zsh developers claim that its better than bash and this seems to be one such thing where bash just ignores newlines in variable without quotes but zsh honors them.

Comment: I think I understand: zsh honors newlines in variable but it does not honor them in $(expression) statements. This looks like a broken behavior to me. Thanks.

Comment: `zsh` does not perform word-splitting on parameter expansions by default, meaning any embedded newlines are treated literally instead of as word-separating whitespace. `setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT` makes `zsh` behave like `bash`. The issue is with `echo $v` vs `echo "$v"`, not the `$(cut ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for education about `SH_WORD_SPLIT` very informative.

Answer (score -1):

As previously mentioned by @chepner, zsh does not behave the same way as bash.

Here is an attempt to make your solution work on both zsh and bash without changing zsh behavior. Give it a try, change your `echo $v` to :

```
echo "$v" | tr '\n' ' '
```